# ServiceStack ServiceExtensions RunAction method

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am looking at the source code of `ServiceExtensions RunAction`. It seems interesting:

```
public static object RunAction<TService, TRequest>(
    this TService service, TRequest request, Func<TService, TRequest, object> invokeAction,
    IRequestContext requestContext = null)
    where TService : IService
{
    var actionCtx = new ActionContext
    {
        RequestFilters = new IHasRequestFilter[0],
        ResponseFilters = new IHasResponseFilter[0],
        RequestType = service.GetType(),
        ServiceAction = (instance, req) => invokeAction(service, request)
    };

    requestContext = requestContext ?? new MockRequestContext();
    var runner = new ServiceRunner<TRequest>(EndpointHost.AppHost, actionCtx);
    var response = runner.Execute(requestContext, service, request);
    return response;
}
```

Does it mean I can use this method to call up methods in other services? Could someone give me a code example of how to 'RunAction' properly?